# Problem with totalling related tables in crystal when both tables have a different number of rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 3 tables. 1 Master and 2 detail tables both with a different amount of rows. I want the total of the qty in detail1 and the total of the qty in detail2 but show them on the same detail line e.g.

(What I Expect)

```
 Total Detail1: 13  Total Detail2: 45
```

What happens is, it multiplies the total of detail1 by the number of rows in detail2 and vice versa e.g.

```
 Total Detail1: 65 Total Detail2: 135
```

65 = number of rows in detail2 (5) x 13

135 = number of rows in detail1 (3) x 45

Is it possible to separate the totalling of these 2 totals?

I am using Running Totals to achieve this currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pair of subreports that only show the report footer, one subreport for each table, and the subreports nestled in the main report's details section. Alternatively, i'd use views to create the totals and use the views in the report. I prefer this method as subreports are slow.

Comment: +1 This is probably your easiest bet for this. I was going to answer with a response that would probably go along with what you were trying to do in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439032/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-iterate-through-a-table-within-a-formula-in-cr), but I think it would end up getting too complicated so I deleted my answer and voted for CodeByMidnight's instead.